# Issues installing Theano in Ubuntu

Tags: python

I am running through the [tutorial](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python) on installing Theanos on a ubuntu machine. I am on the step of installing pygpu which involves cd'ing into the build directory and running the setup script.

However I keep getting the following error. Any insight into what I am being asked for would be appreciated

```
pygpu/gpuarray.c:462:29: fatal error: gpuarray/config.h: No such file or directory
#include "gpuarray/config.h"
                         ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Found a github issue with your problem: https://github.com/Theano/libgpuarray/issues/91

> Either use LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib in your environment or run sudo ldconfig

Comment: Can you expand on that Max ?

Comment: Not sure which path LD_LIBRARY_PATH should be configured to , but running ldconfig did not make any difference

Comment: http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the program was not reading the dependencies, probably something to do with the default directory settings. I got around this issue by going into

/home/(your_username)/libgpuarray/Build and altered the CMakeCache.txt file so that CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS:BOOL=ON
This allowed it to set its own directory paths and I had not more issues.